# What is bet way to Join two tables with many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, join

I am having two tables as

Table 1

```
UserName| MessageId|Message
U1|1|First
U2|2|Hi
U1|3|hello
U4|4|temp
```

Table 2

```
UserName|UnitName
U1|Unit1
U1|Unit2
U2|Unit3
```

I need result Like

```
UserName|MessageId|Message|UnitName
    U1|1|First|Unit1,Unit2
    U2|2|Hi|Unit3
    U1|3|hello|Unit1,Unit2
    U4|4|temp|NULL
```

Can you please help me to find efficient query?

Comment: Please refer this : http://rextester.com/NUDLG26424  This will solve your problem.